# Android Appcompat v7 ActionbarWindow

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, android-appcompat

I'm trying to migrate to Materials Theme. The first step is to import Appcompatv7 but when I add the library to my project and run the app this error occurs...

```
10-24 20:37:11.506: E/AndroidRuntime(13807): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-24 20:37:11.506: E/AndroidRuntime(13807): Process: com.ghsoft.teacher, PID: 13807
10-24 20:37:11.506: E/AndroidRuntime(13807): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field ActionBarWindow of type [I in class Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable; or its superclasses (declaration of 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable' appears in /data/app/com.ghsoft.teacher-1/base.apk)
10-24 20:37:11.506: E/AndroidRuntime(13807):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:106)
10-24 20:37:11.506: E/AndroidRuntime(13807):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:57)
10-24 20:37:11.506: E/AndroidRuntime(13807):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:99)
10-24 20:37:11.506: E/AndroidRuntime(13807):    at com.ghsoft.teacher.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:46)
10-24 20:37:11.506: E/AndroidRuntime(13807):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6018)
10-24 20:37:11.506: E/AndroidRuntime(13807):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
10-24 20:37:11.506: E/AndroidRuntime(13807):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2370)
10-24 20:37:11.506: E/AndroidRuntime(13807):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2480)
10-24 20:37:11.506: E/AndroidRuntime(13807):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
10-24 20:37:11.506: E/AndroidRuntime(13807):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1377)
10-24 20:37:11.506: E/AndroidRuntime(13807):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-24 20:37:11.506: E/AndroidRuntime(13807):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
10-24 20:37:11.506: E/AndroidRuntime(13807):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5725)
10-24 20:37:11.506: E/AndroidRuntime(13807):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-24 20:37:11.506: E/AndroidRuntime(13807):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-24 20:37:11.506: E/AndroidRuntime(13807):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1030)
10-24 20:37:11.506: E/AndroidRuntime(13807):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:825)
```

I hope you can help me out guys. Thanks

Comment: please add your activity code and  project manifest

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should update the appcompat v7 library to latest version.Just try.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.